# Quote a keyword in a Hibernate dialect

Tags: java, hibernate, dialect

I am trying to write a Hibernate dialect that quotes the word definition.

I tried to overwrite the Dialect.quote function but it is final and doesn't allow this.

Currently Hibernate generates this:
`select ..., postingdef0_.definition as definition31_, ... from ...`

And I need it to be:
`select ..., postingdef0_."definition" as definition31_, ... from ...`

Please note the quotes around the word definition.

I also tried to register definition as a keyword ( registerKeyword ) without success.

I would like to solve this in the **dialect** before I change the client code to add back ticks, which seem to be the alternative solution.

Comment: Just for my clarification: why exactly are you trying to quote a column?

Comment: The SQL server I am using gives a syntax error if the quotes are missing for this keyword only.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate do you use?

Comment: The version is 4.1.9

Answer (score 2):

The words defined in via `Dialect.registerKeyword()` will be be passed to `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.IdentifierHelperBuilder.applyReservedWords(Set<String>)` which will do nothing when `hibernate.auto_quote_keyword` is `false` (the default).

Setting it to true might solve the problem but in my case, this defined a lot of other keywords that cause even more problems.

My fix was this code in the new `Dialect`:

```
@Override
public IdentifierHelper buildIdentifierHelper(
    IdentifierHelperBuilder builder,
    DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData
) throws SQLException {
    // Original code
    builder.applyIdentifierCasing( dbMetaData );
    
    // My code: Just define a few keywords which cause problems
    builder.setAutoQuoteKeywords(true); // Force quotes around keywords
    Set<String> sqlKeywords = ImmutableSet.<String>builder()
        .add("VALUE")
        .build();
    builder.setReservedWords(sqlKeywords);
    
    // Original code
    builder.setNameQualifierSupport( getNameQualifierSupport() );

    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: thank you for having talked about `hibernate.auto_quote_keyword`. It's not even on https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html and yet was the trick to make it work on a similar case for me